# When we use hierarchical Navigation Page A to Page B and to Page C. when we press a button Page C it should redirect to home page

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I achieve this,
Page A -> page -> B Page C
then
Page C -> Page A
After that when we press the android back button should not go back like:
Page C -> Page B -> Page A
How can we achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear please include some more details or rephrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

You've added Page A to the Navigation Stack on top of Page C.

What you should be doing is popping Page C and Page B off of the navigation stack to return to Page A.

Here's [more information about Hierarchical Navigation in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin).

When you then press the Back Button on Android, the top page on the Navigation Stack is popped. In your example, Page A is popped and Page C (the page now on top of the navigation stack) is revealed.

#### Visual Explanation

1. Set Page A to your root page

> (aka `MainPage = new PageA();`)

```
----------- Page A ------------- <-- Visible Page
-- Bottom of Navigation Stack --
```

2. Push Page B onto the Navigation Stack

```
----------- Page B ------------- <-- Visible Page
----------- Page A -------------
-- Bottom of Navigation Stack --
```

3. Push Page C onto the Navigation Stack

```
----------- Page C ------------- <-- Visible Page
----------- Page B -------------
----------- Page A -------------
-- Bottom of Navigation Stack --
```

4. Push Page A onto the Navigation Stack

```
----------- Page A ------------- <-- Visible Page
----------- Page C -------------
----------- Page B -------------
----------- Page A -------------
-- Bottom of Navigation Stack --
```

5. Pop Page A off of the Navigation Stack

> (aka Tap the Android Back Button)

```
----------- Page C ------------- <-- Visible Page
----------- Page B -------------
----------- Page A -------------
-- Bottom of Navigation Stack --
```

#### Solution

To return to the root page (Page A) from Page C, use `await Navigation.PopToRootAsync()`.

Here is an example:

```cs
partial class PageC : ContentPage
{
    public PageC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
   
        var popToRootButton = new Button { Text = "Return to Page A" };
        popToRootButton.Clicked += HandlePopToRootButtonClicked;

        Content = popToRootButton;
    }

    async void HandlePopToRootButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();    
}
```